# Dynamically change --cpus-per-task between slurm jobs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, slurm, hpc

I am trying to run a bunch of parallel programmes on a cluster, where I vary the number of CPU:s between jobs.

I tried to use the `SLURM_ARRAY_SUBMIT_ID` to achieve this, which one gets when using `#SBATCH --array`. My current code right now looks like this, although I already tried many other variants. The name of the file is `multi_vector_slurm.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name="Try_openmp"
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=8GB
#SBATCH --output=/dev/null
#SBATCH --array=1-3
export CPUS_PER_TASK=$SLURM_ARRAY_SUBMIT_ID
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=$CPUS_PER_TASK

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

srun ./main_vector.x  >> openmp_results.txt
```

When running this with the command `sbatch multi_vector_slurm.sh` I indeed get 3 jobs, but all of them just run with 1 cpu.

Has anyone encountered something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `--cpus-per-task` along with your `srun` command.

For example,

```
srun --cpus-per-task=1 ./main_vector.x  >> openmp_results.txt
srun --cpus-per-task=2 ./main_vector.x  >> openmp_results.txt
srun --cpus-per-task=3 ./main_vector.x  >> openmp_results.txt
```

From the Slurm Documentation:

> When srun is executed from within salloc or sbatch, there are
> configurations and options which can result in inconsistent
> allocations when -c has a value greater than -c on salloc or sbatch.
> The number of cpus per task specified for salloc or sbatch is not
> automatically inherited by srun and, if desired, must be requested
> again, either by specifying --cpus-per-task when calling srun, or by
> setting the SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK environment variable.